# including object name from list with tukey test results in "for" loop graph

Tags: r, list, tukey

I have a nested list (tukey_full) with the results from various TukeyHSD tests that I have run, and want to include the name of each object in the list as a subtitle in the plot. I have successfully done the plots by using

```
 lapply(tukey_full, plot)
```

and

```
 for(i in tukey_full) {
      plot(i)
    }
```

However, I can't figure out how to add the name of the object in the subtitle, which I can see by using the names function, as with

```
> names(tukey_full)
 [1] "protein_6289_03860"                                            
 [2] "protein_6289_01870"                                            
 [3] "protein_2945_03380_5751_03109"                                 
 [4] "protein_6289_01021"                                            
 [5] "protein_6289_03009"
```

I tried using

```
  for(i in tukey_full) {
  plot(i, sub=(i))
```

and

```
for(i in tukey_full) {
  plot(i, sub=names(i))
}
```

Printing the list gets me one of the following for each entry

```
$protein_6289_01751
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = .x ~ datos_significativos_unknown$cepas)

$`datos_significativos_unknown$cepas`
               diff       lwr        upr     p adj
A-C   -5.1771274 -8.357472 -1.9967829 0.0025429
B-C -4.8750794 -8.770190 -0.9799687 0.0150836
A-B   0.3020481 -2.878296  3.4823926 0.9653298
```

And paste(print()) gets me

```
[1] "list(`datos_significativos_unknown$cepas` = c(2.00490288888889, 2.62596766666667, 0.621064777777779, 0.714833966082775, 1.04596236971821, -0.669004145028336, 3.294971811695, 4.20597296361513, 1.91113370058389, 0.00358339105839034, 0.00217233503326419, 0.429956321252804))"
```

but these don't seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You were really close!

```
c <- 1
for(i in tukey_full) {
    plot(i, sub=names(tukey_full[c]))
    c <- c + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `lapply` you can try this:

`lapply(1:length(tukey_full), function(x) plot(tukey_full[[x]], sub=names(tukey_full)[x]))`